# how to make an app that uninstalls after some specific time

Tags: windows-phone-8

i would like to know if there is a way to make an app in wp8 that uninstall itself after some specific time.
for example i make an app that makes filters on photos, i test this app on my phone, after testing i forget to uninstall it and so i would like to have a timer inside that app so that it can uninstalls itself after some time.

or is there a way to make an app that checks for some apps(that i have developed) on my phone and uninstalls them in some regular time(that is the app wakes app, cheks if that app exist on my phone and if that apps exist on my phone it uninstalls it)?

i thank you in advance for the help

Comment: I strongly doubt you can create an app that can uninstall other apps!!

Answer (score 6):

Installing and uninstalling of app requires more permissions than any app sandbox environment provides to it.

You can check the time when the app was installed to user machine and thus forbid the user for using it post-specific time. Similar to what trial version softwares work like.

Second part of your question clearly violates the user rights. As the requirement is to uninstall other apps using another app. I doubt that this can not be done.

Comment: "You can check the time when the app was installed to user machine and thus forbid the user for using it post-specific time. Similar to what trial version softwares work like." ok i can forbid, but can i also make the app to uninstall itself ?

Comment: uninstalling the app is outside the sandbox environment of app itself. No valid way of doing it. or Atleast i am not aware of such thing.